# shows that if $P(z)$ has no complex zero, then $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I hope someone could enlighten me!

If $P(z)$ is a polynomial, shows that if $P(z)$ has no complex zero, then $\frac{1}{P(z)}$ is bounded.

Comment: You mean if $P(z)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Is there a difference between $P(z)$ and $p(z)$? Are you assuming your function is continuous?  And, if this is homework, what have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry,i think this was in the lemma that trying to prove fundamental theorem of algebra

Comment: sorry, how can I add a comment, I am new here.
Are complex zero and real zero same, both 0i+0=0;

Comment: @Victor I have answered your question in the form of a series of ***Exercises***.

Comment: @onlybluemoon: 1) you can't comment on anything other than your own questions until you reach a certain reputation level. This is to prevent excessive spam. 2) if you want to ask a new question, ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume, for a contradiction, that the function defined by the rule $f(z)=\frac{1}{p(z)}$ is not bounded. In this case, there exists a complex number $z_n$ such that $\left|f(z_n)\right|>n$ for all positive integers $n$. Of course, this implies that $\left|p(z_n)\right|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all positive integers $n$.

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $\lim_{\left|z\right|\to\infty} \left|p(z)\right|=\infty$.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. (Hint: use ***Exercise 1***.)

***Exercise 3***: Prove that the sequence $\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence. (Hint: use ***Exercise 2***.)

***Exercise 4***: Prove that $z\to p(z)$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.

***Exercise 5***: Deduce that $p$ has a complex zero and hence obtain a contradiction. (Hint: use ***Exercise 3*** and ***Exercise 4***.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Excuse me,i can't understand how you finished exercise 4 and 5 and how it help?

Comment: We assume, for a contradiction, that $p$ is not bounded and in ***Exercise 5*** we deduce that this leads to the result that $p$ has a complex zero. (Let us recall that this is a contradiction since we explictly assumed in the beginning that $p$ has no complex zeros.) Please do think about ***Exercise 4*** and ***Exercise 5*** since they are not too difficult to solve.

Comment: @Victor Hint (***Exercise 4***): prove that if $h$ and $k$ are continuous functions from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, then so is $ah+bk$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. Also, prove that $z\to z^n$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Comment: @Theo I absolutely agree with you but perhaps the OP is doing a university course in complex analysis and has already completed a course in real analysis (?). In this case, there might be no way (short of dropping the course) for the OP to learn real analysis "properly" before learning complex analysis.

Answer (score 9):

Amitesh Datta's outlined proof is absolutely correct.  Let me give another approach, which is in some sense more direct (e.g. it is not a proof by contradiction).  The differences between his answer (given first!) and mine are relatively minor.

We may assume that $P(z)$ is nonconstant.

Step 1: For any nonconstant polynomial function $P(z)$, $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} |P(z)| = \infty$.  (This easily reduces to the case of $z$ a real variable, in which case it is familiar from calculus.)

Step 2: If for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ $P(z) \neq 0$, then the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{P(z)}$ is a continuous [indeed holomorphic, but we won't need this] function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  Moreover, by Step 1, $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z) = 0$.

Step 3: I claim that any continuous function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which *vanishes at infinity* -- i.e., has $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z) = 0$ -- is bounded.  Indeed, there exists $R_1 > 0$ such that for all $z$ with $|z| \geq R_1$, 
$|f(z)| \leq 1$.  Moreover, since $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ |z| \leq R_1 \}$ is a closed disk in the complex plane, it is compact and thus every continuous function on $R_1$ is bounded: there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $z$ with $|z| \leq R_1$, $|f(z)| \leq M$.  It follows that $f$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb{C}$ by $\max \{M,1\}$.

Here is another way to construe Step 3: for any locally compact space $X$, one can give a meaning to a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ **vanishing at infinity**: it means that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact subset $K \subset X$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in X \setminus K$.  But in fact this is equivalent to saying that $f$ extends continuously to the **one-point compactification** $X_{\infty} = X \cup \{\infty \}$ of $X$ with $f(\infty) = 0$.  Then, since $f$ extends continuously to a function with a compact domain, it is bounded.  Note that in this case the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ is nothing else than the **Riemann sphere**, and this way of looking at complex functions plays a big role in complex analysis.

Comment: +1 A very nice answer (as usual) since it introduces the OP to the Riemann sphere which is important. I think that this argument is more straightforward than mine because mine secretly uses sequential compactness (which might not be familiar to the OP).

Comment: @Pete: In step 1, I think you meant $P(z)$ should be a *non* -constant polynomial function.

Comment: In step 1 you mean non-constant. Also, I prefer to prove this via the [growth lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39567/for-a-polynomial-pz-prove-there-exist-r0-such-that-if-z-r-then-p/39579#39579) for polynomials, which is just the triangle inequality instead of using calculus. (Ah, I see @Zev beat me to it, but I leave my comment because of the alternative argument).

Comment: @Theo: well, technically speaking I didn't say that one should use calculus to prove it but only that the real variable case is *familiar* from calculus.  In all honesty, looking deep into my heart, whatever way the reader wants to prove this fact is absolutely fine with me.  :)

Comment: :) +1 ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

> "if $p(z)$ has no complex zero, then $\frac{1}{p(z)}$ is bounded"

Not really; the exponential function is one of the simplest counterexamples...